# XAML itemscontrol: contentpresenter visibility doesn't reflect each owned item

Tags: xaml, visibility, itemscontrol, contentpresenter

In ItemsControl items are in a ContentPresenter, so if a item has Visibility='collapsed' its ContentPresenter still have Visibility='Visible'...
([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965523/9456800) is explained this behaviour)

So these 2 examples doesn't show the same result:

This works as I expect:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
    <Button Content="0"/>
    <Button Content="1"/>
    <Button Content="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button Content="3"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

This doesn't work as I expect (UniformGrid reserve the space for the third button also if it is collapsed):

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type System:Int32}">
            <System:Int32>0</System:Int32>
            <System:Int32>1</System:Int32>
            <System:Int32>2</System:Int32>
            <System:Int32>3</System:Int32>
        </x:Array>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Visibility="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource CalculatorConverter}, ConverterParameter=IIF(\{0\}\=2\,\'Collapsed\'\,\'Visible\')}" Content="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Anyone got this problem? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, because the button is not a direct child of the `UniformGrid`. Instead, `ItemsControl` adds a `ContentPresenter` templated with the `DataTemplate` you've defined to the `UniformGrid`. So basically the visual tree resembles this:<sup>*1*</sup>

```
<UniformGrid>
    ....
    <ContentPresenter>
        <Button Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </ContentPresenter>
    ....
</UniformGrid>
```

I think this clearly demonstrates why the space in the grid is reserved even though the button is collapsed. Of course to remedy that you should collapse the `ContentPresenter` instead. It can be achieved by using `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` property:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Visiblity" Value="{Binding ., Converter=...}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

---

<sup>*1*</sup> *The provided code is only an illustration of the visual tree and is not a valid WPF XAML.*

Comment: Yes, you're right: this is the solution ...
I was hoping there was an alternative solution because I would have preferred to be able to define generic "ItemContainerStyle" in order to reuse it ... Instead in this way I have to define it specifically for the model I'm using.